# Is 'my schedule has gone disarrayed' correct?

Tags: grammar

I want to write:

> *I have not been able to follow my schedule*

but in a different way. Can I say:

> *My schedule has gone disarrayed*

to convey the same meaning? If the above sentence is not correct how would a correct one be phrased?

Comment: "has become disarrayed" would be the correct way to use the word in this context, though the meaning is not identical to your starting sentence.

Answer (score 1):

'My schedule is in disarray' or 'My schedule has fallen into disarray' would be more correct. And you can emphasize it by throwing in a 'total'. For example, my schedule is now in total disarray thanks to spending too much time on this website :P

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to something being **in disarray**:

"My schedule is **in complete disarray** this week -- I haven't done anything I intended to do."

Answer (score 0):

'My schedule has **gone awry**.'
says the same thing.

But .a. (tenor) it is slightly old fashioned, and therefore less direct.

And .b. (nuance) it suggests that some outside force has driven it into disarray.